# How to Write a Function that Creates New List Objects for Each Dataframe?

Tags: r

I have several telemetry objects containing animal tracking data filtered by year. I've also created a list containing all of these telemetry objects. I currently have a loop function that calculates and plots variograms for each individual in a given telemetry object. What I'd like to do now is turn my variogram loop into a function that I can lapply to the list of telemetry objects that will calculate variograms and create new list objects for each of my telemetry objects.

Here's a minimum working example using tracking data from the ctmm package:

```
library(ctmm) 
library(ggplot2) 
library(dplyr) 
library(stringr) 
library(lubridate) 
library(sf) 
library(tidyverse) 
library(sp) 
library(scales) 
library(tidyr) 
library(tibble)

data("buffalo")

Cilla <- as.data.frame(buffalo$Cilla) 
Cilla$id<-"Cilla"

Gabs<-as.data.frame(buffalo$Gabs)
Gabs$id<-"Gabs"

Mvubu<-as.data.frame(buffalo$Mvubu)
Mvubu$id<-"Mvubu"

Pepper<-as.data.frame(buffalo$Pepper)
Pepper$id<-"Pepper"

Queen<-as.data.frame(buffalo$Queen)
Queen$id<-"Queen"

Toni<-as.data.frame(buffalo$Toni)
Toni$id<-"Toni"

buffalo2 <- rbind(Cilla,Gabs,Mvubu,Pepper,Queen,Toni)
buffalo2$Year<-year(buffalo2$timestamp)
buffalo2$Year<-as.factor(buffalo2$Year)
buffalo2$UTM.zone<-"12 +datum=NAD27"
buffalo2$timestamp <- ymd_hms(buffalo2$timestamp) 
buffalo2$Timestamp<-buffalo2$timestamp
buffalo2 <- separate(buffalo2, timestamp, c("date","time"), sep= " ", 
remove= TRUE, extra= "merge")

buffalo2 <- buffalo2[, c(8,9,1,2,6,7,11,10)]

data2005<-buffalo2 %>% 
  filter(Year==2005)
data2006<-buffalo2 %>% 
  filter(Year==2006)

Tdata2005<-as.telemetry(data2005, timeformat="auto",timezone="UTC", 
timeout=Inf,datum="NAD27",
         na.rm="row",mark.rm=FALSE,keep=FALSE,drop=FALSE)
Tdata2006<-as.telemetry(data2006, timeformat="auto",timezone="UTC", 
timeout=Inf,datum="NAD27",
                    na.rm="row",mark.rm=FALSE,keep=FALSE,drop=FALSE)

Tdata<-list(Tdata2005,Tdata2006)
names(Tdata)<-c("Tdata2005","Tdata2006")

#Variogram loop
SVF <- function(x, date) {
  SVF <- list()
  for (i in 1:length(x)) {    
    SVF[[i]] <- variogram(x[[i]])
    plot(SVF[[i]], main = paste(names(x[i]), "(", date, ")"))
  }
}

#Applying the variogram function to the list of dataframes with dates
Years<-c("2005","2006")
lapply(seq_along(Tdata), function(i) SVF(Tdata[[i]], Years[i]))
```

So far, my function is able to calculate and plot variograms for the individuals in both of the telemetry objects within my Tdata list (Tdata2005 and Tdata2006). What I'd like to do next is figure out a way to save the variograms for each annual telemetry object as a list, preferably as a separate list for each year(ex: Variograms_Tdata2005 and Variograms_Tdata2006). Is there any way for me to edit my code to make this work? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you can adapt the function to compute (only) variograms, then export for each element of the list (that corresponds to a year) the list containing the different variograms, as follows:

```
SVF_save <- function(x) {
  SVF <- list()
  for (i in 1:length(x)) {    
    SVF[[i]] <- variogram(x[[i]])
  }
  return(SVF)
}

svf_for_save <- lapply(seq_along(Tdata), function(i) SVF_save(Tdata[[i]]))

Years<-c("2005","2006")

### saving as .rds object
for (i in 1:length(svf_for_save)) {    
  saveRDS(object = svf_for_save[[i]], file = paste0("Variograms_Tdata",Years[i],".rds"))
}
```